# Can you make API calls (RESTFUL API) from your own gRPC service using Visual Studio and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, grpc-web

I am a newbie to gRPC, like I literally started to read about it a month ago, and getting to know more of it, because we are trying to implement something like a centralized server that will handle API calls to an external system we have (like DocuSign or Workday for example) using their API.

In order to make this happen, we have created a website in Visual Studio using Razor, and I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/grpcweb?view=aspnetcore-8.0) documentation that tells how to integrate Razor with gRPC, however, what I want now is to do a call from our client (the website) to our gRPC server (that we will create in Visual Studio) to have the server make an API call to workday for example, so we can pull users data, edit and delete data from Workday, using their API.

Is this possible using C# and .NET? I found it is possible to do something like that in Go Lang, but does anyone have a sample code I can use to better understand how to implement this? Or does anyone know if this is even possible?

I found some documentation [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/5-minutes-to-add-restful-apis-for-your-grpc-services-14673c7cd01f) to implement API calls in gRPC but this is in Go, and I need to implement this in Visual Studio with support for .NET and C# which is what we will be using

Comment: Yes.  Your server has a Frontend (HTTP connection from Client to Server) and a Backend (Server to Workday).  You want to setup an Azure Controller in the server like this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717996/azure-custom-controller-api-net-backend  The you can connect to Workday API in the Azure controller : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789493/how-to-authenticate-to-workday-api-in-net-core

Comment: Here is another posting with same question.  Code is showing using OAUTH2 authentication (Not Window Credential) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415944/consume-workday-rest-api-with-oauth-2-0-in-net-mvc

Comment: This looks like a very good example : https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/WorkDay/-/php-workday-class-examples.html